# converting a numeric cell type into a text cell type in ms excel document without changing contents of the cell using open office

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

How to convert a numeric cell type into a text cell type in ms excel document without changing contents of the cell using open office. This cell value is then accessed using java (POI JAR getRichStringCellValue() method of HSSFCELL Object).

Comment: Is this programming related or do you need help on OpenOffice??

Comment: If my answer was useful, please check it as your accepted answer.

Comment: did you find a solution for this yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
HSSFWorkbook wb = ...;
DataFormat format = wb.createDataFormat();

HSSFCellStyle cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
style.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("@")); // or "text"
cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
```